# SQLite foreign key NullPointerException

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm using Android studio , sqlite database
my code was working correctly , but when I added "posid" column to "contacts" table the program doesn't work

logcat while insert contact
 [image]

.........
thanks for everybody can help me

Comment: Why did you add a screenshot of your logcat? Please copy and paste the exact text.

Comment: could you show us your main_activity.xml ?

Comment: You never initialized et4, but it's being referenced in your insertBtn method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't initialize the `EditText et4` and that's the reason for the exception, also when you update the table schema "add column(s)" you should increase your database version, so that android can update the table

```
int DATABASE_VERSION = 2; // instead of 1
```

Comment: thanks a lot ,that solves my problem

Answer (score 1):

You're referring to an EditText reference that has never been initialized.  Namely, et4.

Also, I would suggest not having member variables that hold onto references to your views as this is a common source of memory leaks.  Instead, just call findViewById when you need a local reference to your view.

Comment: thanks a lot ,that solves my problem